# how to know if an array of indexed arrays had the same value more than once?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
 $products[0]['productid']   = 5;
 $products[0]['name'] = "apples";
 $products[0]['seller'] = 1;

 $products[1]['productid']   = 15;
 $products[1]['name'] = "orange";
 $products[1]['seller'] = 1;

 $products[2]['productid']   = 5;
 $products[2]['name'] = "apples";
 $products[2]['seller'] = 2;
 // .... more 5000 products
```

this array is filled by the client with ajax. **I need to make a restriction that `$products` array don't have the same `productid` in any of it's other members.**  as in the invalid data example above `5`

What I do to get that done is by doing this

```
$onlyids = array();
for($x=0; $x < count($products); $x++){
   $onlyids[]=$products[$x]['productid'];//get only productid in an array
}
//remove duplicate members
$onlyids2= array_unique($onlyids);
 //check if there were duplicates
if(count($onlyids) != count($onlyids2)){
   //same id found, reject client inputs
}
```

did I do it correct ? or there is a better performing way. because my way is obviously consume more time on big arrays?

Comment: What you have there is fine in essence - but how are you storing this array? Are you using a database? It just seems very inefficient

Comment: check [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @JBithell it come from the client. if it's ok, I store it in mysql

Comment: @deceze has a great answer - but as an alternative you could upload each item to MySQL and then use an auto increment field for the id to be set automatically

Comment: @JBithell I don't want to make sure that ids is different and store them all. I want to reject the inputs that has the same product and inform the user that data is invalid.

Comment: Why not check it before adding it to the array?

Comment: @RST do you mean on the client side? javascript?

Comment: I don't know your workflow for adding products to this array. Right now it feels like you are allowing everybody to get on board of a bus, once everyone found a seat you start checking tickets and tell people without a ticket to leave the bus. Why not check before they enter?

Comment: @RST "this array is filled by the client with ajax".  yes I do my "tickets checking" on the client side with javascript. but I also need to do the same check on the server side

Comment: Okay I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most performant way is to store found product ids as array keys while you iterate the data:

```
$productIds = [];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (isset($productIds[$product['productid']])) {
        throw new Exception('Duplicate product id ' . $product['productid']);
    }
    $productIds[$product['productid']] = true;
}

echo 'All good';
```

More obscure and inefficient, but a one-liner:

```
if (max(array_count_values(array_column($products, 'productid'))) > 1) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid input');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much . thank you too for your great article about encoding sir. accepting after time restriction